# How to prove that $C\cdot\aleph_0=C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

How can I prove that $C\cdot\aleph_0=C$?

I tried this:

Given that
$k\cdot 1=k$ and $C\cdot C=C$
if $C\cdot C = C \wedge C\cdot 1 = C \wedge  C>|\mathbb N|>1$ then
$C\cdot |\mathbb N|= C$

c is the size of the continuum and k is any cardinal.

Is this correct?

Comment: $\aleph_0$ is produced by the command `\aleph_0`. Inline equations are made with single dollar signs (`$a$` is $a$)

Comment: What exactly are $C$ and $k$?

Comment: Probably c is the size of the continuum and k is any cardinal.
Then the result follows from $c\leq c*\aleph_0\leq c*c=c$ by the Cantor-Bernstein Theorem

Comment: That's what I thought. It would help the question if it were stated explicitly, though.

Answer (score 5):

Observe that
$$
C\le C.\aleph_0\le C.C=C
$$
Now use Cantor-Bernstein theorem to deduce the statement.

For proving that $C.C=C$ you can use decimal expansion of real numbers and the function
$$
f:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to [0,1]\\
f(.r_1r_2r_3\dots,r'_1r'_2r'_3\dots)=.r_1r'_1r_2r'_2r_3r'_3\dots
$$

Comment: Is the prove(that i wrote) valid ?(thanx for the help)

Comment: No, needs some motivations...

Comment: can you help me with one more step

Comment: I need help its something that i need to show tommorow, c=c then what ?

Comment: What's your problem with the proof?

Comment: Can i use k*m=max(k,m) given that cantor theory \p(N)\>\N\

Comment: You should clarify the nature of $f$. People might think it is a bijection.

Comment: Yes I should clarify that we use only infinite decimal presentations...(except for zero)

Comment: $k.m=\max(k,m)$ is not true generally, but you can use $|P(N)|>|N|$ always...

Comment: Thanx k1.M, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If $C$ is the cardinality of the continuum, that is, $C=2^{\aleph_0}$, you can use a direct method, by knowing that $C=|\mathbb{R}|$: write
$$
\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(n,n+1]
$$
Since $|(n,n+1]|=C$, you have the thesis.